# How to CSS: select element based on inner HTML

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<a href="example1.com"> innerHTML1 </a>
<a href="example2.com"> innerHTML2 </a>
<a href="example3.com"> innerHTML3 </a>
```

I want to style the second  only (innerHTML2) using CSS selectors, based on the inner HTML. Is this possible? I've tried using `a[value=innerHTML2]` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Before you use it, read this "bug report" and JQ team response: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9955 It may come handy to know.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is not possible using CSS. You can, however, do it using jQuery. There's a nice [blog post](http://richard2001.blogspot.com/2010/02/select-elements-by-innerhtml-with.html) on it you can read.

Comment: Writing a custom jQuery CSS selector provides the most control

Comment: The ":contains(...)" syntax in that URL worked for me.  But the "[innerHTML=...]" produced no effect for me.

Comment: It might be a good link but does not help here :-)

Answer (score 18):

It's currently not possible for all browsers with css, but with javascript you can do this

Updated w/ working code. JSFiddle link below:

Initial HTML per @whamsicore:

```
<a href="example1.com"> innerHTML1 </a>
<a href="example2.com"> innerHTML2 </a>
<a href="example3.com"> innerHTML3 </a>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myEles = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0; i<myEles.length; i++){
    if(myEles[i].innerHTML == ' innerHTML2 '){
         console.log('gotcha'); 

         //use javascript to style
         myEles[i].setAttribute('class', "gotcha");
    }
}
```

CSS for styling:

```
/* make this look a bit more visible */
a{
  display: block;
}

.gotcha{
  color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/81qqxj23/

Comment: +1 for not thinking jQuery is the be all and end all of JavaScript.

Comment: Is this a misleading answer? I spent an hour before I get into that there is no getElements method. I needed to use document.getElementsByTagName instead.

Comment: @FLICKER answer updated with actual working code.

Comment: @KJYe.Name葉家仁, Thanks. I reverted my downvote :)

Answer (score 12):

Using CSS you can't detect the content of the anchor tag.

`[value=]` would refer to an attribute on the tag

```
<a href="" value="blah"> innerHTML2 </a>
```

Not very useful since the value attribute isn't valid HTML on an `a` tag

If possible, slap a class on that `a` tag.  As that is most likely not possible (because you would've already done that) you can use jQuery to add a class on that tag.  Try something like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){ $('a:contains(innerHTML2)').addClass('anchortwo'); });
    </script>
```

And then use `.anchortwo` as your class selector.

Comment: edited because of the random downvote with no explanation

Comment: This is the closest answer as to why! TO NOTE: css selectors allow detection of attributes, these are predefined in the HTML code, where as innerHTML is a property of the DOM layer. They may resemble access in js, but are two different things, a.href is an attribute over which CSS has knowledge, a.innerHTML is a DOM property, obscure to CSS.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the css nth-child property to access any element and do any changes. i Used it on a website i made to make a logo smaller or bigger based on the width of screen.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of what the css code would look like to help others that may not be familiar with the property or format?

Comment: for example if there is a div with class 'mark' and there are 4 <p> elements inside it, if i want to apply property to all even or odd elements, or even a single element, i can do this by n-th child property, go read about it on w3schools, as they have far better examples with all its variations, much better than what i would give here, i'm pretty bad at giving examples. ;)       https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: Welcome to SO! Looks like this is one of your first answers. Your method is certainly a solution, but generally answers need two things: 1. a new answer to this specific question, which might be "you can't but here's a work around" and a sample of the code to solve the problem, because links go stale/break/move. When you get a chance, check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`pup`](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup), a command line tool for processing HTML using CSS selectors, you can use `a:contains("innerHTML1")`.

For example:

```
$ echo '<a href="example1.com"> innerHTML1 </a>' | pup 'a:contains("innerHTML1")' text{}
 innerHTML1
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<style>
a[data-content]::before {
  content: attr(data-content);
}
a[data-content="innerHTML2"] {
  color: green;
}
</style>
<a href="example1.com" data-content="innerHTML1">&nbsp;</a>
<a href="example2.com" data-content="innerHTML2">&nbsp;</a>
<a href="example3.com" data-content="innerHTML3">&nbsp;</a>
```

Comment: You're not selecting the element by innerHTML. You're selecting by an attribute which has the value "innerHTML1". So, you haven't answered the question.

Comment: by the way @joe-tom, It helps me solve my problem. If something is not possible, ratoupoilu has given an alternate. This is the problem with most newly-enriched-in-reputation stackoverflowians.

Answer (score -11):

This is quite simple with a nth-child selector.

```
<style>
a:nth-child(2) {
  color: green;
}
</style>
<a href="example1.com"> innerHTML1 </a>
<a href="example2.com"> innerHTML2 </a>
<a href="example3.com"> innerHTML3 </a>
```

Edit: Here's the source I found this at. Check here for browser compatability.
Source: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild

Comment: This isn't supported cross browser. IE for example won't support this

Comment: Also it isn't selecting based on inner html it is selecting based on position so it doesn't really answer the question

Comment: As said before, this does not select the element based on the content, but it selects the element based on the index which is not wat the OP asked.