# how to hide div if inner html includes specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
 <div class="showcaseBeds">0 Bedroom</div>
 <div class="showcaseBaths">0.00 Total Bathroom</div>
 <div class="IDX-showcaseBeds">3 Bedrooms</div>
 <div class="IDX-showcaseBaths">3.00 Total Bathrooms</div>
```

I want to hide the div if the showcaseBeds inner html ==  0 Bedroom aswell as 
hide the showcaseBaths if inner html ==  0.00 Total Bathroom

I have found a few jquery solutions that hinged on the attributes but not the inner html.

```
 $('div.item:has()').remove();​
```

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811962/how-to-css-select-element-based-on-inner-html indicates that it is not possible across all browsers, and gives a workaround involving jQuery.

Comment: @AdrianWragg thanks for the link! Ill check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use (You used wrong class)

```
$("div.IDX-showcaseBeds:contains('0 Bedroom')").remove();
$("div.IDX-showcaseBaths:contains('0.00 Total Bathroom')").remove();
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/qDKrD/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
$("div.item:contains('"+ text + "')").remove();
```

Comment: Thanks! so i would include this twice one for each text string im looking to remove

Comment: I tried your suggestion here http://jsfiddle.net/qDKrD/1/ with no luck. Where am I going wrong with syntax?