# How I select these elements in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a markup something similar to below -

```
<div class="nav" id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">------</a></li>
        <li><a href="">------</a></li>
        <li><a href="">------</a></li>
        <li>
            <a class="mainMenuLink" href="index.php?p=account-information"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-3x"></i> Account Information<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="active-menu" href="index.php?p=account-function"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-3x"></i> Account Functions<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
            <ul class='nav nav-second-level in'>
                <li>
                    <a class="subMenuLink" href="index.php?p=create-account">Create a New Account</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="active" href="index.php?p=modify-account-select">Modify an Account</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="subMenuLink" href="index.php?p=">Password Modification</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
  </ul>        
</div>
```

In this markup I want to select  tags that contains 'Account Fuction' and 'Modify an Account'.

This is what I want to select from about Markup -

```
<a class="active-menu" href="index.php?p=account-function"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-3x"></i> Account Functions<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>

<a class="active" href="index.php?p=modify-account-select">Modify an Account</a>
```

Can somebody tell me what is the best way to select these elements in jquery?

Hope somebody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: Your code lack tag <span> and the tag <i> is no content. What tags do you want to select?

Comment: I want to select the <a> tags which contain 'Account Function' and Modify an Account'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to CSS: select element based on inner HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811962/how-to-css-select-element-based-on-inner-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
$("a:contains('Account Functions')");
$("a:contains('Modify an Account')");
```

This way it will find the elements no matter where they are. jQuery is nice isn't it?

Comment: Yes It is....  Can we use this for <th> tag? like `$("th:contains('Emails')")` etc

Comment: @user3733831 Certainly. Just make sure it's in a table.

Comment: thank you. One thing now I want to check these elements have a particular class if not I want to add a class. I tried it something like this -

Comment: `$("a:contains('my link')").hasClass("custom").removeClass("custom").addClass("custom");`

Comment: @user3733831 Here is a fiddle with a [way to do that](http://jsfiddle.net/pgdf2kkc/1/). Basically we go through our element(s), check if it has `.custom`, if it does not then add it. Looks like you have the same idea :)

Comment: @user3733831 No you don't need it. Although if it's the same class your are adding that you are checking all you need to do is: `$("a:contains('Modify an Account')").addClass( "active" )`. jQuery will not add a duplicate class (it will check for you), so you will not need to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#nav").children("ul li").find(".yourelementclass").text();
```

You can do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code `$(".active-menu, .active")`
You can select class active-menu or class active in one statement