# Atom text editor - highlight line based on regex

Tags: atom-editor

Atom is a hackable text editor but I can't find a way to hack it to my needs.
On PC I use Notepad++ and its custom highlighting engine to view very large log files with visual cues to assist me.

I want to be able to highlight individual lines in Atom based on their contents: say the line contains "warning" I want it to be orange or "error" - red.

Answer (score 0):

Atom is build on web technologies, so you can use JavaScript and CSS to alter its behaviour. If, for instance, you type "Warning" into a plain-text document and open the Developer Tools, you will see it is rendered as plain HTML:

`<span class="text plain">
  <span class="meta paragraph text">Warning</span>
</span>`

Unfortunately, there are currently no [CSS selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) for the text inside a tag-pair, so you would have to create a plugin, or package, in JavaScript/Coffeescript. [How to CSS: select element based on inner HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811962/how-to-css-select-element-based-on-inner-html)) provides a good starting point.

Use JavaScript to detect all instances of “Warning” inside the HTML of the editor view, then add a class. You can then use CSS to highlight the line.

Alternatively, you could *probably* create [custom gramma](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/grammar/)r for your log file.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. My file has unstructured log data, such as [2016-05-31 17:10:12] [Warning] Something happened and was logged, I want to highlight all [Warning] lines in my files

Comment: I understood that, maybe my answer wasn't clear enough. Edit incoming!