# Hide a class if it contains a certain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<div class="spanLabel"><span class="boldLabel">END DATE: </span>end date is empty</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.spanLabel').filter(function() {
    return !!($.trim( $(this).text() ) == 'end date is empty');
        }).hide();
```

I want to hide the whole spanLabel div if the word **end date is empty** is present.

Right now, code only works if I get rid of `<span class="boldLabel">END DATE: </span>`

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790860/hide-div-that-contains-specific-text

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you want to achieve. Are you saying that you want to hide the parent `div` if the `span` contains the specified text?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence `end date is empty` belongs to div, not to span, from your html.
Therefore you can use `:contains` to check if the div text has your desired text

```js
$('.spanLabel:contains(" end date is empty")').hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="spanLabel">
  <span class="boldLabel">END DATE: </span> end date is empty
</div>

<div class="spanLabel">
  <span class="boldLabel">END DATE: </span> end date is not empty
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, anytime :)