# How to select anchor element by its text using DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm intercepting into an html page and need to find all anchors having "Select All" in their inner html.

I need to write a piece of JavaScript to find all the anchors and then Click them.

I'm going to write a javascript like this:

```
// there is no method like getElementByInnerHtml so I don't know what to do
var anc = document.getElementByInnerHtml('Select All');
anc.click();
```

I'm not able to use jquery or any other language specific methods. Only standard HTML DOM methods are available.

Comment: What have you tried? Where's your code? What errors are you getting? What debugging have you done?

Comment: Check out this question. I think you can find your answer there.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811962/how-to-css-select-element-based-on-inner-html

Comment: Hey downvoters, I don't know what to try. I know how to getelement by class name or attribute but could not find anything related to anchor text. Please look into context before asking for what have you tried.

Comment: @ChrisLove, did you miss to put the link in your comment?

Comment: Yes, yes I did LOL

Comment: @ChrisLove, I think it will help me. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the code and thanks @ChrisLove for hint.

Actually the code in the referred post was not correct and using below code I could do what I needed to do.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        if (x[i].innerHTML == "Select All")
            x[i].click();
    }    
</script>
```

Note that you need to use `getElementsByTagName` not `getElements` which is mentioned in the other post.