# How to find the element using css-selector through Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

1. For this code need a css-selector, x-path is available
2. Following is the x-path such as:

   ```
   //div[@class='item-display-name' and text()='edit']
   ```

HTML of the element:

```
 <div class="item-display-name">edit</div>
```

Comment: There is no css selector that lets you select an element based on innerHTML. However, you can select all elements by class name and check if the innerHTML matches your string using JavaScript, as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4812052/12690946

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To locate the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use the following [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.item-display-name")))
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

### Update

As per your comment, **No** you can't include the text **edit** within the [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors). You can find a detailed discussion in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException with “span:contains('string')”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883572/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidselectorexception/47884814#47884814)

Comment: I also want to include text "edit "  into the selector , for this css-selector there are 7 more results.

Comment: @nikhilcodes Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: How to convert this xpath-- "//*[contains(text(),'$type')]
 into Selenide css selector

Comment: @nikhilcodes Seems like a different question all together. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement. Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.